# Flutter: Floating action button fixed location

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sample Code'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Text"),
          ),
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Text"),
          ),
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Text"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Container(
          height: 50.0,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    );
```

Whenever the keyboard shows up to enter text into a `TextField` the `FloatingActionButton` moves up to the top of the keyboard which will look like this:

[image: FloatingActionButton]

What I want is that the button stays in the bottom navigation bar and does not move when the keyboard shows up. I added `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,` to the `Scaffold`, which prevents the button from moving but also stops my `ListView` from moving to stay visible when the keyboard shows up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe there's a more elegant way of doing this? but this will solve your immediate problem.

There's a nice little plugin to detect the keyboard visibility [here](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_visibility).
All you need to do then is to listen to the keyboard visibility state and hide the FAB when the keyboard is visible.

Sample:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:keyboard_visibility/keyboard_visibility.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'SO Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool keyboardOpen = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(
      onChange: (bool visible) {
        setState(() => keyboardOpen = visible);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sample Code'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Text")),
          TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Text")),
          TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Text")),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Container(height: 50.0),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: keyboardOpen
          ? SizedBox()
          : FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you! But I'm still curious if there might be a more elegant way to handle this.

Comment: Yes, there is a more elegant way, which is using `positioned widget`. Have a look at [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgtPleVwxBQ)

Answer (score 10):

Wrapping the floating action button inside a `positioned widget` did not work for me.  However, in combination to adding in your Scaffold the property

resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,

You can also use the SingleChildScrollView widget with padding using the MediaQuery.of method...

```
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: () {
      showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          isScrollControlled: true,
          builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                  child: AddTaskScreen())),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent);
    },
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the property inside Scaffold
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false

It will solve the problem immediately..

Answer (score 0):

inside Scaffold Use this property.
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false

Just Like :

```html
return Scaffold(
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sample Code'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Text"),
          ),
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Text"),
          ),
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Text"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Container(
          height: 50.0,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    );
```