# Make the Floating Action Button to a fixed location

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm developing an application with a FAB on the navigation bar, and when the keyboard appears FAB goes up with the keyboard. I want FAB to stay in the navigation bar as a fixed location.

**Normal UI**

[image]

**With Keyboard**

[image]

I've tried using *keyboard_visibility: ^0.5.6* as mentioned in the earlier question. [Flutter: Floating action button fixed location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56308831/flutter-floating-action-button-fixed-location)

However this plugin is deprecated, so I'm not able to use it.

This is the code related to FAB button.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    extendBody: true, 
    body: IndexedStack(
      children: pages,
      index: index,
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: TabBarMaterialWidget(
      index: index,
      onChangedTab: onChangedTab,
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: () => print('Hello'),
    ),
    floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
  );

  void onChangedTab(int index) {
    setState(() {
      this.index = index;
    });
  }
```

What needs to be done to solve this ? (If there is any other plugin like the above please let me know how to use it to solve this issue / or any other method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

```
bool? resizeToAvoidBottomInset
```

> if there is an onscreen keyboard displayed above the scaffold, the
> body can be resized to avoid overlapping the keyboard, which prevents
> widgets inside the body from being obscured by the keyboard.

```
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to put the **Floating Action Button** inside the **bottomNavigationBar** then it will be located at the bottom always.